# Teradata : Transpose columns to rows

Tags: sql, teradata

**Query :**

```
select * from <table>
```

**Answer set :**

[image]

We need to transform the above answer set as below. We need to get the column name entry in each row with their corresponding values as shown below:

```
Col1    Col2

JOB1    161
JOB2    38
```

I tried following ways from below links (But didnt work out) :

- http://forums.teradata.com/forum/database/transpose-rows-to-columns-0
- http://forums.teradata.com/forum/database/transpose-columns-to-rows

**Note :**

- Operation is not performed on large tables.
- Is it possible without using volatile tables

Comment: What do you mean by `didn't work out`? The links show both solutions, UNION ALL or a CROSS JOIN, additionally in TD14.10 there's a TD_UNPIVOT table function.

Comment: @dnoeth followed your query only .. but could not get the column name in rows

Comment: `SELECT 'Col1', job1 FROM TAB UNION ALL SELECT 'Col2', job2 FROM TAB`

Comment: @dnoeth Make your last comment an answer so I can he can accept it and I can upvote it, except I think he wants SELECT `'JOB1'...`.

Comment: Of course you're right, it's `SELECT 'Job1', job1 FROM TAB UNION ALL SELECT 'Job2', job2 FROM TAB`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The links you posted show both possible solutions, if you need to get the column names as values you need to write them as literals:

```
SELECT 'Job1', job1 FROM TAB 
UNION ALL 
SELECT 'Job2', job2 FROM TAB
```